# How do I define this XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Right now I have a working XSD for:

```
<Portal layout="blah" />
```

Now, I want to extend the system, so I can do (but I also want to support the OLD style above):

```
<Portal>
  <layout xsi:type="type1">
    <attribute ... />
    <attribute ... />
    <attribute ... />
  </layout>
</Portal>

<Portal>
  <layout xsi:type="type2">
    <otherAttribute ... />
    <someVal ... />
  </layout>
</Portal>
```

So I want to have the legacy simple string and then a more complex type switched on the xsi type... You should not be able to mix the two.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I try to simplify the problem like this: the element `Portal` allow more complex combinations, such as either a `layout` expressed as an attribute or expressed as element. so we have the following content models:

```
<Portal layout="blah" />

<Portal>
    <layout >
       <attribute ... />
       <attribute ... />
    </layout>
</Portal>
```

To do so, you will define a base type that is a superset of both content models:

```
<xs:complexType name="PortalBase" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="layout" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
       <xs:attribute ref="layout"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

This base type accepts `portal` elements with optional `layout` defined as attribute or element. We can derive by restriction a first type which will accept only `layout` attribute:

```
<xs:complexType name="layoutAttribute">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="PortalBase">
                <xs:attribute ref="layout" use="required"/> 
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

We can derive a second type that accepts only `layout` defined as element:

```
<xs:complexType name="layoutElement">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="PortalBase">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="layout" minOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute  ref="layout" use="prohibited"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>

    </xs:complexType>
```

we can use them in the schema to define the `portal` element as having a type `PortalBase`:

```
  <xs:element name="portal" type="PortalBase"/>
```

Then we can use them in the instance documents to declare which derived type we are using:

```
<portal xsi:type= "layoutElement">
    <layout attr1=""/>
</portal>
```

or:

```
<portal xsi:type= "layoutAttribute" layout="blah"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will play around with this!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [Mixed Content attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp) in your definition for the Portal type.

Something like:

```
<xs:element name="Portal">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true"> <!-- this allows "old school" text content -->
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0"> <!-- this allows use of one of the two layout types, or none at all. -->
      <xs:element name="Layout1" type="layout1" />
      <xs:element name="Layout2" type="layout2" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The restriction here is you cannot define elements of different types with the same name within the same "grouping" element (in this case the choice element)